# How to create this UI in XML?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I'm working on a recyclerView and there is a problem for me to make it's view: in the view I have an imageView but right-top corner and left-bottom corner have cuts.
How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: you need to some research then after you may post your question -check it -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024059/cutting-the-corners-off-a-layout

Comment: I saw this link before. But when I set this shape to my main layout and then load my image into imageView, the image will fill all the main layout

Comment: Which image please post in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`ShapeableImageView`** provided by the Material Components Library:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/mont"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.Cut"
    ../>
```

With:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.Cut" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">32dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">32dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ask your designer to provide this image and add it as a src for your imageview.

Comment: why you give this kind of answer instead of comment?

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation to comment :p

Comment: Then discribe your answer as a perfect